# Check corrupted pictures on Synology?

Tags: nas, jpeg, synology, file-corruption, pictures

On my computer I use the `jpeginfo` command for checking if my pictures are corrupted or not. I am trying to use the same command on my Synology.

I tried to manually install `jpeginfo` on my DS212 (following [this process](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=25807)) but the `jpeginfo` says `Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62`.

Do you know how I can install this command? If you know an other command I can also try to use it.

NB:

- current DSM version: `DSM 5.1-5021 Update 2`
- `ipkg` is already installed.

Comment: Would it be easier to simply run jpeginfo on your machine? (While the synology folder with pictures are mounted on your machine)

Comment: @Darius For a large amount of pictures, I think that your solution is better but in my case, sometimes I need to check several files.